# index function not assigned to duck

Tags: python

I'm stuck here

INSTRUCTIONS

Use the `.index(item`) function to find the index of "duck". Assign that result to a variable called duck_index.

Then `.insert(index, item)` the string "cobra" at that index.

CODE

```
animals = ["aardvark", "badger", "duck", "emu", "fennec fox"]
duck_index = animals.index("duck")  

animals.insert(2, "cobra") 

print animals
```

Comment: Given the clear description, why, when you `animals.insert`, aren't you using `duck_index`? Also: what's your question?

Comment: Seriously, the instructions give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the question...

```
animals = ["aardvark", "badger", "duck", "emu", "fennec fox"]
duck_index = animals.index("duck")  # retrieve the index of "duck" and assign it to variable duck_index
animals.insert(duck_index, "cobra") # insert "cobra" at duck_index
print(animals)
```